# Losing adorner layer after ListView had no items

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview

I'm using attached behavior to add sorting to GridView columns from here: http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2009/08/04/wpf-automatically-sort-a-gridview-continued/

It is working fine, if I don't use following code:

```
      <ListView.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ListView">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListView">
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListView.Style>
```

Problem appears, using this sequence of steps:
1) fill list with items, click on header to sort it, sorting glyph appears
2) clear list
3) fill list again, sorting glyph is not visible

I subscribed to SizeChanged event in attached behavior, to catch the moment, when list goes from empty to full, to redraw sorting glyph, but GetAdornerLayer(columnHeader) returns null, I guess it is not rendered yet and does not have adorner layer yet.

Question is, how to catch right moment to redraw missing glyph (or to get adorner layer, when it exists)?

Comment: You can try to *wait* for render (`Dispatcher.Invoke( ..., DispatcherPriority.Render);`). But I think sorting has something to do with `ListCollectionView` itself, so simply setting sorting there will be enough. How do you *clear* list? By calling `Clear()` of what? Maybe you are accidentally clearing sorting.

Comment: I clear list by calling Clear, sorting is not cleared - it is still there, issue is only with repainting.

Comment: I've sorted it out, problem was, that GridViewSort had property SortedColumnHeaderProperty which was holding reference to sorted column header. So when list would be cleared and would be filled again, column headers were recreated and that reference was not used in rendering anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I've sorted it out, problem was, that `GridViewSort` had property `SortedColumnHeaderProperty` which was holding reference to sorted column header.

So when list would be cleared and would be filled again, column headers were recreated and that reference was not used in rendering anymore.